# Load posts in div with slideUp/slideDown using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, slidedown, slideup

I'm trying to load content from wordpress pages into a div on a custom template using links.

I have one div that is hidden, and should be displayed with slideDown when content is loaded into it.

I have several links to different pages that I want to be loaded into this one div by onClick, or something similar.

> Example:
>   Lets say I have the following links:
>   
>  - Link 1 (home)
>   
>  - Link 2 (about)
>   
>  - Link 3 (contact)

If a visitor clicks these links something like this should happen:

> Click link 2 --> load into div --> div gets displayed with slideDown
>   or similar.
>
> Click link 3 --> previous loaded content fades out and content of link
>   2 fades in
>
> Click link 2 (again) --> similar action as by click og link 2...
>
> Click link 1 --> clears div and hides it by slideUp or similar.
>
> If Link 2 or 3 is active, and the user clicks the same link again -->
>   similar action as by click of Link 1

I have found some bits of code to help me on the way, but I'm not quite there yet. 
Heres what I have so far:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
      $('#navigationMenu a').click(function() { // When a menu item is selected
            $('#maincontent').load($(this).attr('href')); // Load its linked page into the div
            return false; // And prevent it following the link
      });
});

function toggleSlider() {
    if ($("#maincontent").is(":visible")) {
        $("#sec-content").animate(
            {
                opacity: "0"
            },
            600,
            function(){
                $("#maincontent").slideUp();
            }
        );
    }
    else {
        $("#maincontent").slideDown(600, function(){
            $("#sec-content").animate(
                {
                    opacity: "1"
                },
                600
            );
        });
    }   
}

</script>
```

I have found this code in related posts here on SO, and this makes me load the content into the div with slideUp/slide/down functionality.
BUT it closes the div by click on link 3 (in the example), so I'll have to click the link again to load it once more.
And the home link, Link 1, doesn't do what I want yet.

Hope someone with a little more knowledge about this can help me out here.
Is it at all possible to do?

Thanks!

---- Edited code 02/08/13 ----

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
      $('#navigationMenu a').click(function() { // When a menu item is selected
            $('#maincontent').load($(this).attr('href')); // Load its linked page into the div
            return false; // And prevent it following the link
      });
});

var lastData;
$(function () {
    $("a").click(function(event) {
        loadData($(this).attr("href"));
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

function loadData(data) {
    if(lastData == data) {
        $("#maincontent").slideUp();
    } else {
        $("#maincontent").html(data);
        $("#maincontent").slideDown();
    }
    lastData = data;
}

</script>
```

The result can be seen at http://tobba.org/no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try having a function that says: When a link is clicked, see if it was the last link clicked. If so, then slideUp(). If not, then get the data to go in there, and then once the data is available, fill the box and slideDown.

This example might get you halfway, you'll still need to use $.get or $.load to get the data you want. NOTE: lastData is declared outside of the scope of the function so that it doesn't lose its value when the function ends:
http://jsfiddle.net/turiyag/9na6K/

```
function loadData(data) {
    if(lastData == data) {
        $("#dataview").slideUp();
    } else {
        $("#dataview").html(data);
        $("#dataview").slideDown();
    }
    lastData = data;
}
```

Comment: Geat, this got me a few steps closer to what I want. Thanks!
I added this bit of code to load the content into the div, instead of just the link:

`$(function() {
      $('#menu a').click(function() { // When a menu item is selected
            $('#dataview').load($(this).attr('href')); // Load its linked page into the div
            return false; // And prevent it following the link
      });
});`

But now the link appears just before the content is loaded in the div, how can I make it so the link doesn't get displayed in the div, only the content of the linked page?

Comment: That code shouldn't have any issues. Can you post your edited code?

Comment: Thanks again for taking time to help with this. I've updated the original post with the edited code, and also a link to where it can be viewed in action. Also I wonder how I can get the "home" link to close the div a first click. Now I have to click twice on home to close it.

Comment: Look into jQuery's "get" function. That will let you get the data you need and use it instead of just passing in the URL.
Secondly, you'll need to erase the code you had initially (before the "var lastdata" statement), as it no longer applies.
Third, your selector "#navigationMenu a" is better in this case than simply "a", and I would use that to get the links to respond to click events.

Comment: Fourth, to get the desired effect on the home button, you'll need to assign a different click function to the home button, and make sure that you don't assign the first click function to the home button. See this example:  http://jsfiddle.net/turiyag/ZYmuN/

Comment: Thanks! I added the .get function to in the first segment like this:
`var lastData;
$(function () {
    $('#navigationMenu a').click(function(event) {
        .get(loadData($(this).attr('href')));
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});` and I added `return false;` right above `lastData = data;` to prevent following of link. But it follows the link anyway. What have I done wrong this time? Sorry for not understanding this yet. I'm learning.

Comment: you're looking for "event.preventDefault()", it's more reliable.

Comment: I tried that too, but it still follows the link. I must have something wrong in my code. Now My code looks like this: `var lastData;
$(function () {
$('#navigationMenu a.home').click(function(event) {
        $('#maincontent').slideUp();
  lastData = null;
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#navigationMenu a:not(.home)').click(function(event) {
        .get(loadData($(this).attr('href')));
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});`

Comment: `function loadData(data) {
 if(lastData == data) {
        $('#maincontent').slideUp();
    } else {
        $('#maincontent').html(data);
        $('#maincontent').slideDown();
  
    }
    event.preventDefault();
 lastData = data;
};`

Comment: Try calling it as the first line of the function. Can you post your code to JSFiddle? I think your code is messed up around the "get" function call.

Comment: I see, yeah, your problem is your call to "get". See here (
http://home.edgemontgeek.com/dev/stackoverflow/14730695/) for a clearer example. Note, you'll need to look at the source. If you have Chrome, I strongly recommend looking at it using the Developer Tools, and making breakpoints in the Source. If you don't have Chrome, I recommend getting it. It's great for web dev.

Comment: Thank You So Very Much! I saw the loadData problem there! Now It works as I want it to!